# Firebase - save data only if all writes were successful

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have users and posts (inside the Firebase database). Every time I create a post, I need to add this post to the user (that created the post) as well. Thus, I have to write data to the database twice.

What if one of them fails? Is there a way to only "commit" the writes if both were successful? Something like transactions in PHP.

Comment: Just check if the `users` snapshot exists and if it does add `post` details to the database...Edit your post with code snippet of how what you got so far  ....

Comment: Well, I don't have any specific code at all. This is just a theoretical thought.  I know I could to it manually by checking everything after saving but often there is a more convenient way of doing this (e.g. with something firebase offers)

Comment: So all you want is to check if the user exists and only if it does then add the post details to its firebase right?

Comment: No, I know that the user exists. But every user has the child "createdPosts" where you store the ids of the posts he created. So I need to create a post, grab its id and store it inside the "createdPosts" of the user. Thus, I need to save sth. to the database twice. And what if the post is created and saved, but then the connection is lost? Then the post isn't saved to the user's "createdPosts". This could cause errors when grabbing the post and its owner later on. That's what I want to prevent